# Macで使用可能なC#のコードメトリクスツールは存在するか

Tags: c#, unity3d

UnityのゲームをMonoDevelop/C#で開発していますが、C#のコードメトリクスを計測ツールが見つからなくて困っています。

Mac上でC#に対応したコードメトリクスツールがご存知の方は教えていただけると幸いです。